# Xbox One sign in not working after Unity package update to 1707 QFE 1 Release

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, xbox-live

I have successfully published my game and can sign in with the 1705.4 package.  After updating to the 1707 QFE 1 version the sign in stops working.  I'm not doing anything outside of dragging and dropping the prefab onto the scene.  While in Unity the sign in works perfectly and shows initially the "Sign In" version of the button, and then once pressed it shows the generic data.

Once this is built and I test it in Visual Studio, I don't get the sign in version of the button, and the button state shows invalid data.

I'm not sure what I am missing since this worked previously, and seems to work while in the editor.  I also don't seem to get any errors that I can see.  Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Screenshots:

- [In Editor With One Sign in (Correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXymS.png)
- [Visual Studio View (Incorrect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqupN.png)

**Update** - Starting to think my solution was corrupted...  Starting over instead of building Unity over the old solution file and I seem to have better luck.  Will post again if I can get it fully working again.

**Final Update** - The new "clean" solution file seemed to work and the PlayerProfile prefab will now automatically sign in when loaded.  I couldn't get the multi-user prefabs to work so I went back to the single sign-in, but I'll assume that is a different problem for now.  When I attempted to sign in the button just kind of froze in the grey "sign in" state, and never did anything after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the multiuser prefab and was getting an Access Denied error being logged in the debug output window in Visual Studio while attached to the Xbox One.  It turned out that I needed to add uap:SupportedUsers setting as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/multi-user-applications

That will only work on the Xbox One and not from the same game running on a PC.

Hopefully this will address your problem too.

Comment: Thank you Todd, I'll go back and see if adding that code will fix the problem I was having with the multiuser prefab.